# Java with Cucumber scenario order

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, gherkin

I am working on an automation project.

My first scenario is the login-feature. I work on a SaaS, and I need to be logged in before.

So I was thinking about a first login.feature scenario and a second scenario to fill a form.

I have two files:

> login.feature
>
> fill_form.feature

I launch my tests with

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @login,@form"
```

So it opens two windows, but the execution is not working as expected: it launches the two scenarios at the same time.

For it to work, I need to make only one feature file, but it is not what I want for my architecture.

Suggestions are welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct (you do not want code duplication) but instead of reusing feature file you should reuse step. You have two options here:

1. Backgrounds

You can specify which step should be called before all scenarios in feature file. For example:

```
Background:
  given I logged in

Scenario: Fill a form
  then I filled a form

Scenario: Some other scenario
  then "here is some work for other scenario"
```

2. Calling steps from step definitions

Create a step definition which calls the other ones. In your case it would mean creating a fill form step which will login at the beginning.

Comment: I have tried the background solution. But in your proposition, given I logged in, is "**I logged in**" the Scenario name ?

Comment: "I logged in" is the name of step. "Background" in this case works the same as "Scenario" block. So you put a name of the Background scenario (if you want) and the you put steps (can be more than one) just like in "Scenario" block.

Comment: Ok, it works, the two scenarios are launching. But, in my second scenario, ui elements are not recongnized..

Answer (score 0):

As I assume you have to run the test in which you try to Login and then fill the form.
For that, you don't need to create two different feature file

You can create your feature file like this

**Scenario:** I Login as a user.

**Given** I Login with valid credentials.

**When** I should navigate to form.

**Then** I should fill up all details.

All these steps will link to the Step-definitions.

Comment: I don't want duplicate code, so I have isolated the login scenario

Comment: In this case, you can call that step definition for another scenario. It can be a common step @vieroli

Comment: do you have an example ?

Comment: @vieroli Sure!!

Answer (score 0):

Feature file

**Feature:** I Login and fill all information

**Scenario:** I Login as a User, to fill valid information in a form

**Given** Start application from a Login page

**When** I Login with a valid user credentials

Step-Definition class(which includes all your steps only, from which you call methods from another class to perform tasks )

```
public class Some_functionality extend DriverInitializer {

WebDriver webDriver; 

@Given("^Start application from a Login page$")
public void start_application_from_signin_page() throws Throwable {

    webDriver = driverInitilizer();
}

@When("^I Login with valid user credentials")
public void login() throws Throwable {
    LoginSteps loginsteps = new LoginSteps();
    loginsteps.signinAsUser(webDriver);
}
```

}

now you have to create another class to define your steps methods

```
public class Loginsteps{

public void signinAsUser(Webdriver webDriver){
 //your code here
}
```

}

you can call "signinAsUser" method anywhere you want to use by

```
LoginSteps loginsteps = new LoginSteps();

loginsteps.signinAsUser(webDriver);
```

and you can initiate Driver in a separate class

```
public class DriverInitializer{


public WebDriver driverInitilizer(){
//your code to initialize driver
SetProperty...
return webdriver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In cucumber all scenarios is run **order by alphabetical** (so @form before @login). You can rename yours scenarios to @001-login, @002form, @003...

If you use Maven, you can add a copy/replace with `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin` and `com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer`

Sample:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-order-scenarios</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target name="copy">
                    <copy
                        file="src/test/resources/steps/scenarios/login.feature"
                        tofile="src/test/resources/steps/run/001-login.feature" />
                    <copy
                        file="src/test/resources/steps/scenarios/form.feature"
                        tofile="src/test/resources/steps/run/002-form.feature" />
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>replace order</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <basedir>${basedir}</basedir>
                <includes>
                    <include>src/test/resources/steps/run/001-*.feature</include>
                </includes>
                <token>login</token>
                <value>001-login</value>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```